# After jQuery fadeTo, CSS :hover stops working

Tags: jquery, css

The div "#menu" becomes opaque after 3 seconds of loading the page.

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu').delay(4000).show().fadeTo('slow', 0.2);
});
```

In my CSS, I have a :hover-function so that the div ceases to be opaque once a mouse hovers over it:

```
#menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

The jQuery works fine - the div becomes opaque after 3 seconds. But then the :hover does not work anymore. Why is that so, and could anyone help me with a solution, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because setting `fadeTo()` will result in the final opacity value being set on the element in an inline style. This means that you cannot easily override that style from a rule in an external stylesheet. One method is to use `!important`, however this is not best practice and should be avoided.

Another way would be to add a class to fade the element, allowing CSS's `transition` to perform the opacity fade, and then using selector specificity to override the style on `:hover`. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#menu').addClass('faded');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#menu {
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

#menu.faded {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#container #menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

Note that the key here is the use of the `#container` prefix on the `:hover` class to make the selector more specific. You can use whatever parent element suits your DOM structure, this is just an example.

Comment: Wonderful, this worked very well - - thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `fadeTo` method is writing an inline style of `opacity: 0.2` to `#menu`. This is difficult to override due to [how specificity is calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

You should instead apply a helper class (`.faded`) to `#menu` after the 4 second delay to achieve the faded effect.

That way, you can still override the opacity style on `#menu:hover` in plain CSS.

```js
$('#menu').delay(4000).queue('fx', function() {
  $(this).addClass('faded');
});
```

```css
#menu {
  transition: 1s;
}

#menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.faded {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
```